# How do you track what caused a move in your reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Being a rep addict (and just waiting for this one to be voted down by the "not programming related" police), but also being a keen participant, the more questions I answer the less I know what causes movement in my reputation.  I find myself periodically trawling my list of answers trying to figure it out.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553/track-your-reputation), but it seems to show exactly the same information as my user tab.  I've also looked through uservoice but I didn't find anyone asking for a list of reputation changes by date.  How do you do it?  Do you do it?

In truth, being a sociable animal I think that I am really hoping that discussions will have sprung around the questions/answers I participated in - but I know that issue is well covered elsewhere.

**Edit:** How predictable that the first thing to happen is a down-vote - sigh :-(

Comment: Simon, from experience, if you mark questions like this as community wiki ones, people are far less likely to mark you down.

Comment: thanks David, that's a useful tip.  I'd vote you up if I could :-)

Comment: you can;) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212942/why-should-stack-overflow-faq-be-community-owned#213005

Answer (score 8):

You raise a good point, I can see it getting difficult under the current UI to tell what you've done recently thats causing a stir.  Especially if someone is asking something of you, you may have no idea that they responded to your answer.  Possibly some UI improvements could be made to show the latests things you've posted that have been voted on.

Answer (score 6):

The benefit of the http://sof.modos.org/tracker/update/your-user-number-here page is that it only shows what's changed between visits to the page. However it doesn't show the cause of decreases in reputation caused by your own downvotes or other people downvoting your questions or answers.

As long as a down vote happens on it's own the cause will be shown on the modos.org page. But a downvote can be masked by an upvote to the same Question or Answer leaving it's vote tally unchanged whilst your rep has been reduced by -2. (Although the same effect could be had by you voting down two posts, as down voting costs you -1 rep per down vote.)

You can see your own down votes on the votes tab of your user page. You are the only person who can see that information.

The Reputation tab on your user page is the only place to view down votes to your questions. You can select part of the graph by click and dragging the mouse to view the votes over a specific time period, however the data isn't updated in real-time so you may have to wait a number of hours before you can see the cause of a down vote. Any user can see this information.

Answer (score 4):

You can highlight a section of the reputation graph in your user profile to reduce the number of entries on the right-hand side of the graph.  Just select the date range in question to narrow down the suspects.

Comment: this would be perfect if it were up to date.

Answer (score 3):

There is also "Responses" tab on your user page. It shows what other people responded to you and you can follow the discussions from there.

Answer (score 2):

I think making it a little bit difficult to track this is a design *feature*.  StackOverflow doesn't really do enough to encourage/enable users to provide even a minimal amount of follow-up for their answers.

So until they address this more adequately, the most effective way to track reputation for the current day is to actually go back and visit old answers, which you can track via the 'recent' and 'responses' tab on your user page.  While you're there checking votes you'll notice if someone asks for clarification or points out a simple mistake, and you can respond or correct it.

Answer (score 1):

There is the reputation graph on your user page, but that seems to be updated in a batch job and, thus, is not particularly useful for finding out why your rep just changed, but more for looking back last week to see how your reputation changed.

Answer (score 0):

that one you linked to will show you the changes to your rep... you just have to visit it more than once, obviously.

Comment: sorry, nickf, don't quite understand your answer, would you mind clarifying?

Comment: The page tracks updates to your rep. To do so, it has to store what your rep was at a certain point in time. Therefore your first visit is your starting point. Any time you visit after that, the page is able to track what happened to your rep between the last visit and your current one.

Answer (score 0):

I look at my user page, and I've got a total of 32 in the left column under "Answers".  My reputation is 197.  They claim an up vote is worth 10 points.  So how can my reputation be any less than 32*10=320?  I haven't ever voted anything down, so no points were subtracted that way.  If anyone voted down any of my answers, that'd subtract 2 votes per downvote.  But if the rating of my answers is the sum of up and down votes, for the score to be the same total but have down votes present, that means there'd be an extra number of upvotes equal to the number of downvotes, resulting in 8 more points of reputation than are visible by looking at the score of my answers.  My reputation has also never changed by anywhere near 200 points in a day, it's not even equal to 200 total.

I hardly care what particular value my reputation is, but I'm obsessive/compulsive enough that if someone gives me a simple formula for something, it drives me nuts if the data doesn't fit the formula.

Please, for the love of god, tell me that reputation is broken or random, so I can ignore it from now on.

Comment: Maybe some of your upvoted answers are on "community wiki" questions (nobody gets rep +/- from these kinds of questions).